# Input field with two buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form with one input field, but two buttons. The idea is to check in or out with a code. The process comes to the php file, where it ends with just a blank page. What´s wrong?

**EDIT**
I changed "btn_in" to "inputAnst_nr" And now it works to reg in. BUT, how to i fetch wich button is pressed?

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-inline well" id="usr_stamp" name="usr_stamp" method="post" action="php/usr_time_reg.php">
  <div class="control-group">
    <input id="inputAnst_nr" name="inputAnst_nr" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Ange Anst. nr" type="tel">
      <button id="btn_in" name="btn_in" class="btn btn-lg btn-info primary col-sm-offset-1" type="submit">In</button>
      <button id="btn_out" name="btn_out" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger primary col-sm-offset-1" type="submit">Ut</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $("#btn_in").on('click', function() {
    $("#usr_stamp").attr("action", "php/usr_time_reg.php");
  });
  $("#btn_out").on('click', function() {
    $("#usr_stamp").attr("action", "php/usr_time_reg.php");
  });
});
```

**PHP**

```
//Check if POST is empty
if(!empty($_POST)){

    //Check if POST is "inputAnst_nr"
    if(!empty($_POST['inputAnst_nr'])){

        //Put POST_btn_in in variable
        $posted_anst_nr = $_POST['inputAnst_nr'];
```

Comment: Why the JS? - Edit due to being a tad too fast at commenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the same name attribute value for both buttons, just make sure you designate the appropriate value. Example:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['btn_in_out'])) {
    $status = $_POST['btn_in_out']; // In or Out depending on which one you clicked
    echo $status;
}

?>

<form class="form-inline well" id="usr_stamp" name="usr_stamp" method="post">
    <div class="control-group">
    <input id="inputAnst_nr" name="inputAnst_nr" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Ange Anst. nr" type="tel">
        <button id="btn_in" name="btn_in_out" type="submit" value="In">In</button>
        <button id="btn_out" name="btn_in_out" type="submit" value="Out">Ut</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3m8RDa)